# Customizing Venn Diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections, venn-diagrams, pattern

For my work, I need a Venn diagram with three circles and the intersecting split into two by a line. [image]

I used an answer from Tex.SE, but I do not know how to use it to draw the intervening line, and shade it as in the figure. Can someone help me out?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{venn circle/.style={draw,circle,minimum width=6cm,fill=#1,opacity=0.4}}

  \node [venn circle = red] (A) at (0,0) {$A$};
  \node [venn circle = blue] (B) at (60:4cm) {$B$};
  \node [venn circle = green] (C) at (0:4cm) {$C$};
  \node[left] at (barycentric cs:A=1/2,B=1/2 ) {$A \cap B$}; 
  \node[below] at (barycentric cs:A=1/2,C=1/2 ) {$A \cap C$};   
  \node[right] at (barycentric cs:B=1/2,C=1/2 ) {$B \cap C$};   
  \node[below] at (barycentric cs:A=1/3,B=1/3,C=1/3 ){$A \cap B \cap C$};
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you reference the answer at Tex.SE you mentioned, that we also can have a look at it?

Comment: Related on how to calculate intersections and fill paths: [Create biconcave lens](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62906/create-biconcave-lens/62919#62919)

Comment: You can draw Venn diagrams easier by using the [`venndiagram`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/venndiagram).

Answer (score 5):

Probably you can refine it a bit more, but I think this will basically answer your question. What you need to do is to construct a path, where you can work on and use to create your desired pattern or fill. Therefore you calculate the intersections of your circles and pass it to coordinates. These coordinates you can use to calculate the angles between the center of the circles and the intersection points, finally creating your shape you want to fill using arcs. To create the intersection line separating the overlap region of A,B and C, you basically calculate the intersecting point of circle B and the line between the two intersecting points of A and C.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{venn circle/.style={draw,circle,minimum width=6cm,fill=#1,opacity=0.4,text opacity=1}}

  \node [name path=A, venn circle = red] (A) at (0,0) {$A$};
  \node [name path=B, venn circle = blue] (B) at (60:4cm) {$B$};
  \node [name path=C, venn circle = green] (C) at (0:4cm) {$C$};

    % intersection points between circles A and B
    \path [name intersections={of = A and B}];
    \coordinate (AB1)  at (intersection-1);
    \coordinate (AB2)  at (intersection-2);

    % intersection points between circles B and C
    \path [name intersections={of = B and C}];
    \coordinate (BC1)  at (intersection-1);
    \coordinate (BC2)  at (intersection-2);

    % intersection points between circles A and C
    \path [name intersections={of = A and C}];
    \coordinate (AC1)  at (intersection-1);
    \coordinate (AC2)  at (intersection-2);

    % constructing path from AC1 to AC2 and calculating intersection point with circle B
    \path [name path=AC] (AC1)--(AC2);
    \path [name intersections={of = AC and B}];
    \coordinate (ACB1)  at (intersection-1);

    % calculate angles from center of A/B to intersection points
    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{A}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{AB2}{center}}
    \let\AABtwo\pgfmathresult

    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{A}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{AC1}{center}}
    \let\AACone\pgfmathresult

    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{B}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{AB2}{center}}
    \let\BABtwo\pgfmathresult

    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{B}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{ACB1}{center}}
    \let\BACBone\pgfmathresult

    % calculate angles from center of B/C to intersection points
    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{B}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{ACB1}{center}}
    \let\CACBone\pgfmathresult

    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{B}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{BC2}{center}}
    \let\BBCtwo\pgfmathresult

    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{C}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{AC1}{center}}
    \let\CACone\pgfmathresult

    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{C}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{BC2}{center}}
    \let\CBCtwo\pgfmathresult

    % calculate angles from center of A/C to intersection points
    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{A}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{AC1}{center}}
    \let\AACone\pgfmathresult

    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{A}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{AC2}{center}}
    \let\AACtwo\pgfmathresult

    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{C}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{AC1}{center}}
    \let\CACone\pgfmathresult

    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{C}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{AC2}{center}}
    \let\CACtwo\pgfmathresult

    % draw patterns
    \pattern[pattern=horizontal lines, pattern color=red]
    (AB2) arc[start angle=\AABtwo, end angle=\AACone,radius=3cm] -- (ACB1) --
    (ACB1) arc[start angle=\BACBone, end angle=\BABtwo,radius=3cm]; 

    \pattern[pattern=horizontal lines, , pattern color=blue]
    (BC2) arc[start angle=\BBCtwo, end angle=\BACBone,radius=3cm] -- (AC1)
    (AC1) arc[start angle=\CACone, end angle=\CBCtwo,radius=3cm];

    % draw separation line
    \draw [thick] (AC1)--(ACB1);

    % print annotations
  \node[left, fill=white, fill opacity=0.5, text opacity=1, inner sep=1.5pt]
    at (barycentric cs:A=1/2,B=1/2 ) {$A \cap B$}; 
  \node[below, fill=white, fill opacity=0.5, text opacity=1, inner sep=1.5pt]
    at (barycentric cs:A=1/2,C=1/2 ) {$A \cap C$};   
  \node[right, fill=white, fill opacity=0.5, text opacity=1, inner sep=1.5pt]
    at (barycentric cs:B=1/2,C=1/2 ) {$B \cap C$};   
  \node[below, fill=white, fill opacity=0.5, text opacity=1, inner sep=1.5pt]
    at (barycentric cs:A=1/3,B=1/3,C=1/3 ){$A \cap B \cap C$};
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

[image]