# Different highlight or filling of circles in Venn diagram with 3 sets

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, circles, venn-diagrams

The `venndiagram` package is used to draw the three sets Venn diagram.

How can I fill subsets of this diagram with different shade, lines, symbols like pluses `+` etc?

The desirable interface of commands can be like `\shade{\fillOnlyB}{white!85!black}` to set the shade like in example  or `\fill{\fillOnlyB}{+}{50}` to fill with pluses the `50%` part of the diagram.

The usage of different colors (except for shades of grey) is prohibited.

The MWE is the following:

```
    \documentclass[14pt]{memoir}

    % no INLIGNED opportunity to use RUSSIAN in arrows, see commented \draw commands
    %http://mirror.macomnet.net/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/venndiagram/venndiagram.pdf
    \usepackage{venndiagram}
    %rename circles
    \makeatletter
    %\renewcommand*{\@venn@label@A}{$Z$} 
    %\renewcommand*{\@venn@label@B}{$X$}    
    %\renewcommand*{\@venn@label@C}{$Y$}
    \renewcommand*{\@venn@label@A}{} 
    \renewcommand*{\@venn@label@B}{}    
    \renewcommand*{\@venn@label@C}{}
    \makeatother

    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand*{\@venn@shade}{white!85!black}
    \makeatother
    \begin{document}

    \begin{figure} 
        \begin{center}
            \resizebox{0.95\linewidth}{!}{
                %>{\columncolor[gray]{0.9}} % doesn't work with \rowcolor
                \begin{venndiagram3sets}[labelOnlyA={${\mathit{3}}$},labelOnlyB={${\mathit{1}}$},labelOnlyC={${\mathit{2}}$},
                    labelOnlyAB={${\mathit{4}}$},labelOnlyAC={${\mathit{6}}$},labelOnlyBC={${\mathit{5}}$},labelABC={${\mathit{7}}$},
                    labelNotABC={${\mathit{8}}$}]
                    \setpostvennhook
                    {
                        \draw[<-] (labelA) -- ++(135:3cm) node[above,align=left] {$Z$ };
                        \draw[<-] (labelB) -- ++(45:2.2cm) node[above,align=left] {$X$ };
                        \draw[<-] (labelC) -- ++(-45:3cm) node[right, align=left] {$Y$};
                        \draw[<-] (labelABC) -- ++(0:3cm)
                        node[right,text width=4.2cm,align=flush left, align=left] { ${\mathit{7}}$ };
                        \draw[shorten >=-1.7cm,shorten <=2.4cm,<-] (labelABC) -- ++(-180:2cm)
                        node[left,text width=2.6cm,align=flush left, align=left] { $U$ };
                        \draw[<-] (labelNotABC) -- ++(-100:1.2cm)
                        node[below,align=left] %,text width=5cm
                        {${\mathit{8}}$}; %
                    }
                    % the interface to fill circles or their parts
                    % \fillACapCNotB
                    % \fillOnlyB
                    \fillACapCNotB    
                \end{venndiagram3sets}
            }
        \end{center}
        \caption{Venn diagram with differently filled parts of circles}\label{fig-ViennDiagramm}
    \end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why would colours be prohibited? Anyway, you can just use different shades of gray.

Comment: Or use non-coloured patterns.

Comment: @cfr, thank you for the useful comment. The question is updated. I need non colored-patterns because of requirements of a publishing house.

Comment: Related question: [Customizing Venn Diagram](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/300856/124842)

Comment: Then I would look at the non-inherently-coloured patterns in the Ti*k*Z manual, I think.

Comment: However, there seems no straightforward way to do this. The package doesn't use `pgfkeys`, for example. I'm not sure, but I think you'll have to redefine every fill macro to use a pattern or (better) to take some arbitrary Ti*k*Z options.

Comment: You may find some pretty drawings here: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/venn-diagram/

Comment: The `venndiagram` package was only intended for very simplistic diagrams. If you want anything more complicated it's much better to use `tikz` directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unsatisfactory in all sorts of ways (and possibly inadvisable), but here the `tikzpicture` is patched with a command which patches a subset of the venn diagram filling commands (if defined), cancelling the fill and enabling additional keys to be passed to the paths.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{venndiagram}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\def\patchvenncmds#1{%
  \pgfutil@for\@cmd:={#1}\do{%
    \expandafter\ifpatchable\expandafter{\csname\@cmd\endcsname}{]}{%
    \expandafter\patchcmd\expandafter%
      {\csname\@cmd\endcsname}{]}{,.. this/.try]}{}{}%
    \pgfutil@namelet{\@cmd @orig}{\@cmd}%
    \expandafter\patchvenncmd\expandafter{\@cmd}}{}}}
\def\patchvenncmd#1{%
  \expandafter\renewcommand\csname#1\endcsname[1][]{%
    \tikzset{.. this/.style={fill=none,##1}}\csname#1@orig\endcsname}}
\makeatother
\preto\tikzpicture{\patchvenncmds{%
fillA,fillB,fillC,fillAll,fillNotA,fillNotB,fillNotC,% <- % is important
fillNotA,fillNotB,fillNotC,fillNotABC,fillOnlyA,fillOnlyB,fillOnlyC,%
fillACapCNotB,fillBCapCNotA% ...etc
}}{}{}  
\begin{document}
\begin{venndiagram3sets}[
  labelOnlyA=$3$,labelOnlyB=$1$,labelOnlyC=$2$,labelOnlyAB=$4$,
  labelOnlyAC=$6$,labelOnlyBC=$5$,labelABC=$7$,labelNotABC=$8$]              
\fillACapCNotB[pattern=north east lines]
\fillA[pattern=north west lines]
\fillBCapCNotA[pattern=crosshatch dots]
\fillNotABC[pattern=dots]
\end{venndiagram3sets}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @MarkWibrow, excellent picture, many thanks!